# My Google result is displaying incorrect URL

Tags: hijacked

We had our website as .php for 3 years, and recently it has been getting hacked, and just switched to an ASP.NET CMS template I wrote from scratch as it is more secure and should prevent these issues.

Unfortunately, some of the .php pages still show up in the google results, and some of our search results are hijacked.  If you do a search on google for wholesale used tires.  You will see a site with our title, and our description, yet with another url.  The url stealing our search result is www.wanxiangsh.com/, when it should be displaying http://www.usedtires.com.  Yet, it still directs the user to http://www.usedtires.com but not giving my customer google ad-revenue.  As if it was somehow stealing it. But when I type www.wanxiangsh.com into my browser it displays a chinese chemical company.  Any insight into what is going on here? Does google somehow have a corrupt cache of our website?

If you view the record I received on our site below that I received from google, you sill see that there is a suspicious url_box_1 field with the value www.wanxiangsh.com at the bottom of the record.

AutoDetectedBrowser: Firefox 4
AutoDetectedOS: Windows 7
IssueType: lr_dmca
Language: en
agree1: checked
agree: checked
companyname: Usedtires.com
country_residence: US
description_of_copyrighted_work: Copyrighted website is being displayed in
a URL that is not owned by me. It is stealing google adsense revenue and
visitors to my site.
dmca_signature: Howard Levy
dmca_signature_date_day: 19
dmca_signature_date_month: 04
dmca_signature_date_year: 2011
first_and_last: Howard Levy
first_name: Howard
hidden_product: websearch
last_name: Levy
location_of_copyrighted_work: www.usedtires.com
represented_copyright_holder: Howard Levy
url_box_1: www.wanxiangsh.com/

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could try reporting to Google, but that may not get you very far. Is it possible the url is redirecting b/c of your ISP forwarding 404 errors. I worked off a server that did that once when no custom 404 page was set up.

You can make 301 redirects for pages you know about by checking the intended URL that the server was trying to find and then setting the correct URL as a variable and then writing a header to redirect.

I'm more familiar with the PHP side, but I'm sure it's similar... HTH.